# create 2 text file with random content via powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to create 2 text file with random content via powershell. But , I am getting very strange characters. How can we create random content with alphanumeric characters ?

```
for ($i=1; $i -le 2; $i++)
{
    $out = new-object byte[] 1073741824; (new-object Random).NextBytes($out);           [IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("c:\temp\file$i.txt", $out)
}
```

output :

```
Àº"”x¯'p¦²5ÐÃ?•š‚«ÉPj×æÈµ¼ÛZxD¶GH 6¤rå›èKˆÍÖŒwûó>X±) È_UðõYv¡°ûÖ»LyàÞ8ä´‚‹^úD(Dàf:ë§X×O‚ïBrª×ÒÿÑ*‚`Õsý¦jdÈ°yf«Ò
   96:  ¤!     Ž¶õrá†(DW^TÙ.ww’ír>¹>ÈbC,Â-4…`       Ñ~Š–4ä<Ìq–»|—Ê&4—Pý·ª®Ze"”ýJù}á^        6qH§¬§¶¯+bs,r€!Çàè–‰ÖµNp„lžM
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I would go with creating a quick reusable function that would take the length of the string you wanted and output like this:

```
$filepath = "C:\file1.txt"
$filepath2 = "C:\file2.txt"
#-lines is the number of lines you want. -length is the length of each line.
$file1 = Get-RandomAlphaNum -lines 2 -length 250
$file2 = Get-RandomAlphaNum -lines 4 -length 250
$file1 | Out-File -FilePath $filepath
$file2 | Out-File -FilePath $filepath2

Function Get-RandomAlphaNum {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param (
    [int] $length = 0,
    [int] $lines = 1
  )
  $output = "";
  # Create specified $number of -lines
  for ($num = 1 ; $number -le $lines; $number++) {
    # create an alphanum line of specified -length 
    $output += -join ((0x30..0x39) + ( 0x41..0x5A) + ( 0x61..0x7A) | Get-Random -Count $length  | ForEach-Object {[char]$_;});
    # This adds you newline/carriage return at the end of each line 
    $output += "`r`n"
  }
  return $output
}
```

You could add a multiplier in, insert some newlines, or whatever to meet whatever end output you are looking for. For example, you could add a loop that produced 8 characters for each count of length, inserting a space between.

Comment: I am getting `Out-File : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Encoding'. The argument "aiQprqbnI9eMRZfsNohj6530UJkDcwxdA72vtVP8Y4GW1KmHyBTuzFOESCXlgL" does not belong to the set 
"unknown,string,unicode,bigendianunicode,utf8,utf7,utf32,ascii,default,oem" specified by the ValidateSet attribute. Supply an argument that is in the set and then try 
the command again.`

Comment: Try again with the updated out-file. piping out should fix it

Comment: ok now , I want to create 500000 lines. how can we create it ?

Comment: Have you even tried? Took me about 3 seconds to think of `$file1 = 1..500000|%{Get-RandomAlphaNum -length 250}` to create a 500,000 line file for `$file1`

Comment: As @TheMadTechnician writes, you can generate as many lines as you like by piping the count 1..500000 which means every number between 1 and 500000. You could also add a loop to your function that would take a number of lines in as a parameter. I will add an example above.